# Given a string find the first embedded occurrence of an integer

Tags: java

This was asked in an interview:

> Given in any string, get me the first occurence of an integer.
>
> For example
>
> **Str98** then it should return **98**
>
> **Str87uyuy232**  -- it should return **87**

I gave the answer as loop through the string and compared it with numeric characters, as in

```
if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
```

Then I got the index of the number, parsed it and returned it.  Somehow he was not convinced.
Can any one share the best possible solution?

Comment: S/He might be looking for regex version of answer

Comment: Did you fail to continue from the first digit  you encounter to the last contiguous digit?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two issues with this solution.

1. Consider the test cases - there are 2 characters '8' and '7', and they both form the integer 87 that you should be returning. (This is the main issue)
2. This is somewhat pedantic, but the integer value of the character '0' isn't necessarily less than the value of '1', '2', etc. It probably almost always is, but I imagine interviewers like to see this sort of care. A better solution would be

   if (Character.isDigit(c)) { ... }

There are plenty of different ways to do this. My first thought would be:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < string.length() && !Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) i++;
int j = i;
while (j < string.length() && Character.isDigit(string.charAt(j))) j++;
return Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i, j)); // might be an off-by-1 here
```

Of course, as mentioned in the comments, using the regex functionality in Java is likely the best way to do this. But of course many interviewers ask you to do things like this without libraries, etc...

Comment: As to your number 2, I believe the character value for 0 IS always less than 1, it follows ASCII values:  http://staffweb.londonmet.ac.uk/~chalkp/java/sbu/book/appa/appa4.htm

Comment: In ASCII this is of course true, but what if the system isn't using ASCII? Java (which I used here) might handle it, but it's possible that the system isn't using ASCII - as I said: pedantic

Comment: @mfrankli - The question is tagged as [tag:java], but I agree. Different encodings _could_ define it differently.

Comment: But the question is tagged as Java, so java is what matters for this question.  It would be an important thing to bring up in an itnerview, mention systems that use Unicode (0 is still less than 1 in Unicode).  But for java, it is still valid to do the comparison that the OP did.  Additionally, there is likely overhead introduced by using Character.isDigit, which makes the OP's method the better solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you say a Regex would likely be the best way to do this? It just seems like too much for such a simple task to me.

Comment: fair point RE the overhead. The best thing to do in an interview is probably to mention alternatives, recognize trade-offs, etc

RE regex: I say it's better from the unix-style thought process that if you have a tool that does something, you should use it. I agree that in this case, it's simple enough that there is essentially no argument whatsoever for using regex - it's neither simpler to implement nor more effective.

Comment: @Danny Who are you addressing?  No one on this thread suggested regex.

Comment: @Danny - In terms of maintainability, the RegEx solution is much less code to maintain, especially for the simple situation like this. In general, RegEx takes the biggest hit when compiling the pattern, and less so for the actual parsing. Since I'm a _big_ fan of having simpler (ie. easier to maintain) code until I can show that I get a needed speed increase from it (ie. with a profiler), and can get a big enough speed boost by changing it.

Comment: I haven't tested it but from reading the code it looks that it would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on line 4 if if only number of the String is at the end of the word (like Str98).

Answer (score 51):

With a regex, it's pretty simple:

```
String s = new String("Str87uyuy232");
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
matcher.find();
int i = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
```

<sub>([Thanks to Eric Mariacher](http://eric-mariacher.blogspot.com/2008/11/java-extracting-only-first-integer.html))</sub>

Comment: Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
What does the above does??

Comment: `\\` escapes the `\` so that the regex picks it up. `\d` matches a "digit" (0-9). "+" says "1 or more". `.matcher(s)` runs the string through the compiled pattern to give you a `Matcher` that you can then do things with, like `.find()`, which sets itself to the first instance matched.

Comment: @harigm I have to disagree with this being the best answer for an interview question.  Questions like this tend to be algorithm/data structure questions that you are expected to use algorithms for.  So when the interviewer asks, "What is the performance of this solution"?  You can't really give an answer with a regex solution unless you are quite familiar with Java's implementation.  In this case, breaking the string into an array and looping would really seem to be the right answer.  You can then explain how it can be performed in O(n) time and show an understanding of strings and arrays.

Comment: @StefanH - I agree that being able to talk about basic data structures and algorithmic complexity are important in an interview, but I also want to know that the candidate understands the tools available in the language that apply to such problems. Also, discussing maintainability and pro/con is important as well. Ideally, I would hope to see _both_ solutions (regex and non-regex) come out of the ideal candidate with a good discussion of the two ways to do it. (note to self: file this away for future use)

Comment: @StefanH - In general, I find that almost 90% of what (most) developers do is at a _much_ higher level than low-level data structures and algorithms. While I agree that a solid foundation there is essential, I put a much higher value on being able to correctly wield the abstractions available to quickly, efficiently, and maintainably get things done.

Comment: What's with the `new String`?

Comment: @cdeszaq I suppose it depends on the sort of job you are applying for.  While I agree that showing the "easiest" implementation is useful in an interview, like you said 90% of developers would do it that way, why set yourself apart?  You learn very little of what the developer actually knows about programming.  Interview questions are not generally for real world solutions, they a re designed to gauge a developers skillset, and questions like these are generally to gauge their knowledge of data structures, and algorithmic thinking.

Comment: @SteveKuo - Just created for testing purposes. Like I said, I grabbed the code from someone else, and changed it only minimally.

Comment: @StefanH - I agree with you on what these sorts of questions are used for, but my point is more that it's better to reach for the RegEx solution first, but then dig deeper as the performance or other needs are brought up.

Comment: @SteveKuo - I'm not sure I agree with you that it's _bad_ code. Not strictly required, sure, but it's not "bad". If you disagree and think that it _is_ bad, please by all means show me how it's "bad".

Comment: More secure code
        boolean found = matcher.find();
        int i = found ? Integer.valueOf(matcher.group()) : -1;

Answer (score 31):

Using `java.util.Scanner` :

```
int res = new Scanner("Str87uyuy232").useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();
```

The purpose of a `Scanner` is to extract tokens from an input (here, a `String`). Tokens are sequences of characters separated by delimiters. By default, the delimiter of a `Scanner` is the whitespace, and the tokens are thus whitespace-delimited words.

Here, I use the delimiter `\D+`, which means "anything that is not a digit". The tokens that our `Scanner` can read in our string are "87" and "232". The `nextInt()` method will read the first one.

`nextInt()` throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if there is no token to read. Call the method `hasNextInt()` before calling `nextInt()`, to check that there is something to read.

Comment: It seems to also return `87` for `"87uyuy232"`.

Answer (score 7):

```
String input = "Str87uyuy232";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*").matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Worked nice for me. A clean solution, concise & checks for no match as well .. which I think is a critical detail

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you wanted non-regex and not using other utilities.

here you go

```
public static Integer returnInteger(String s)
{
    if(s== null)
        return null;
    else
    {
        char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
        Integer value = null;
        boolean isPrevDigit = false;
        for(int i =0;i<characters.length;i++)
        {
            if(isPrevDigit == false)
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(characters[i]))
                {
                    isPrevDigit = true;
                    value = Character.getNumericValue(characters[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(characters[i]))
                {   
                    value = (value*10)+ Character.getNumericValue(characters[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the string was "myString 000"?  You would not be able to identify a null string from a string that actually has the int 0

Comment: @StefanH A int can't be null, but if you really want that, then wrap it with an object class.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood what i was saying.  You cannot differentiate between the input string being null, and 0 being the first integer in the string, using the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to a lower level too.  A quick look at [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) reveals that alphabetical characters start at 65.  Digits go from 48 - 57.  With that being the case, you can simply 'and' n character against 127 and see if that value meets a threshold, 48 - 57.

```
    char[] s = "Str87uyuy232".toCharArray();
    String fint = "";
    Boolean foundNum = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        int test = s[i] & 127;
        if (test < 58 && test > 47)
        {
            fint += s[i];
            foundNum = true;
        }
        else if (foundNum)
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(fint);
```

Doing this wouldn't be good for the real world (different character sets), but as a puzzle solution is fun.