# Check and extract a number from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm writing a program where the user enters a String in the following format:

```
"What is the square of 10?"
```

1. I need to check that there is a number in the String
2. and then extract just the number.
3. If i use `.contains("\\d+")` or `.contains("[0-9]+")`, the program can't find a number in the String, no matter what the input is, but `.matches("\\d+")`will only work when there is only numbers.

What can I use as a solution for finding and extracting?

Comment: If you want to extract the first number, not just the digit from the input string, see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I went with looks like this:

```
Pattern numberPat = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher1 = numberPat.matcher(line);

Pattern stringPat = Pattern.compile("What is the square of", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher2 = stringPat.matcher(line);

if (matcher1.find() && matcher2.find())
{
    int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher1.group());                    
    pw.println(number + " squared = " + (number * number));
}
```

I'm sure it's not a perfect solution, but it suited my needs. Thank you all for the help. :)

Answer (score 283):

try this

```
str.matches(".*\\d.*");
```

Comment: what does the double backslash do?

Comment: To explain: .* means any character from 0 to infinite occurence, than the \\d+ (double backslash I think is just to escape the second backslash) and \d+ means a digit from 1 time to infinite.

Comment: It's not alien magic it's cryptic BS, back from the days when no one could do this stuff but the engineers who invented it because it's basically a secret code that only the creators know until they share it.

Comment: Modified, because if only one digit is present, the solution is good enough, no need to have 1 or more digits in this case.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to extract the first number out of the input string, you can do-

```
public static String extractNumber(final String str) {                
    
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean found = false;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            sb.append(c);
            found = true;
        } else if(found){
            // If we already found a digit before and this char is not a digit, stop looping
            break;                
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Examples:

> For input "123abc", the method above will return 123.
>
> For "abc1000def", 1000.
>
> For "555abc45", 555.
>
> For "abc", will return an empty string.

Answer (score 14):

`s=s.replaceAll("[*a-zA-Z]", "")` replaces all alphabets

`s=s.replaceAll("[*0-9]", "")`  replaces all numerics

if you do above two replaces you will get all special charactered string

If you want to extract only integers from a `String s=s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")`

If you want to extract only Alphabets from a `String s=s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")`

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 13):

I think it is faster than regex .

```
public final boolean containsDigit(String s) {
    boolean containsDigit = false;

    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (containsDigit = Character.isDigit(c)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return containsDigit;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see extracting.If you want to extract the number in string , you can easily edit this code.

Answer (score 12):

The code below is enough for "Check if a String contains numbers in Java"

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9])");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Here is ur string");

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("Hello "+m.find());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I could not find a single pattern correct.
Please follow below guide for a small and sweet solution.

```
String regex = "(.)*(\\d)(.)*";      
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String msg = "What is the square of 10?";
boolean containsNumber = pattern.matcher(msg).matches();
```

Comment: This works really well. The only thing you need to watch out for is if the string contains a back slash. If it does, then I think this will produce an "illegal escape character" error.

Comment: this is the best

Answer (score 10):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z].*[0-9])");
Matcher m = p.matcher("TEST 123");
boolean b = m.find();
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: First line has minor error, bracket is missing in String.

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z].*[0-9]))");

Comment: also, this doesn't work... the test works, but 123TEST won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following pattern:

```
.matches("[a-zA-Z ]*\\d+.*")
```

Comment: However if the user is polite and says `"please"` this will fail. Plus in OP's example, there is a "?" to account for.

Comment: Are you sure you've fixed it?

Comment: This expression does not work for an answer like `"10"` for sample.

Answer (score 3):

Below code snippet will tell whether the String contains digit or not

```
str.matches(".*\\d.*")
or
str.matches(.*[0-9].*)
```

**For example**

```
String str = "abhinav123";

str.matches(".*\\d.*") or str.matches(.*[0-9].*)  will return true 

str = "abhinav";

str.matches(".*\\d.*") or str.matches(.*[0-9].*)  will return false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String hasNums(String str) {
        char[] nums = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        char[] toChar = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            toChar[i] = str.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (toChar[i] == nums[j]) { return str; }
            }
        }
        return "None";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I was redirected here searching for a method to find digits in string in `Kotlin` language, I'll leave my findings here for other folks wanting a solution specific to Kotlin.

Finding out if a string contains digit:

```
val hasDigits = sampleString.any { it.isDigit() }
```

Finding out if a string contains **only** digits:

```
val hasOnlyDigits = sampleString.all { it.isDigit() }
```

Extract digits from string:

```
val onlyNumberString = sampleString.filter { it.isDigit() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
String text = "ddd123.0114cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}","");
    try {
        double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
        System.out.println(text +" contains numbers");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(text+" not contains numbers");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't only want to look for a number but also extract it, you should write a small function doing that for you. Go letter by letter till you spot a digit. Ah, just found the necessary code for you on stackoverflow: [find integer in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742680/given-a-string-find-the-first-embedded-occurrence-of-an-integer). Look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.matches(".*\\d+.*")` only works for numbers but not other symbols like `//` or `*` etc.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is at the start of UNICODE, so you can do something like this:

```
(x >= 97 && x <= 122) || (x >= 65 && x <= 90) // 97 == 'a' and 65 = 'A'
```

I'm sure you can figure out the other values...