# check string with delimiter expected

Tags: android, split, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I want to split string got from bluetooth. i'm using

```
StringTokenizer  splitStr = new StringTokenizer(readMessage, "\\|");
String numberSpeed = splitStr.nextToken();  //splitStr[0].replaceAll("\\D+","");
String numberTorque = splitStr.nextToken();  //splitStr[1].replaceAll("\\D+","");
numberSpeed = numberSpeed.replaceAll("\\D+","");
numberTorque = numberTorque.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Did it with split string before.
If i get corupted data without delimiter the app crashes while trying to do impossible.

- How to check if there is delimiter or not and then proceed split or skip it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check for delimeter in string by contains() method

```
if(str.contains("_your_delimiter")) {   //for safe side convert your delimeter and search string to lower case using method toLowerCase()
     //do your work here
}
```

Comment: `if(readMessage.contains("|")){
StringTokenizer  splitStr = new StringTokenizer(readMessage, "\\|");
numberSpeed = splitStr.nextToken().replaceAll("\\D+","");
numberTorque = splitStr.nextToken().replaceAll("\\D+","");  
}`  still it tries to split it and crashes

Comment: can you post the logcat. i mean to say which exception it throws.

Comment: It worked actually... Do not know what i changed, but it worked :D

Comment: And how to check if string contains number? `if(str.contains("_your_delimiter && D+")) {`??? Sorry i dont know all these \\DD and so on commands...

Comment: see here..this might help you what you want to do. see the accepted answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590901/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-java

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I use it in my app.

```
String container = numberSpeed ;
String content = "\\D+";
boolean containerContainsContent = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(container, content);
```

It will `return true` if it has delimiter, and `false` it not.

Use that  with an `if statement`.
**ex.**

```
if(containerContainsContent){
//split it 
} else {
//skip it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quote from tokenizer docs: `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code.`

Try to user `String.split()` instead.

```
if(str.contains(DEILIMITER)) {
     String tab[] = str.split(DEILIMITER);
    //enter code here

}
```