# How to check if a string contains only specifc characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a long string of digits in Java. I want to find of the string contains any one of the digits 0,1,4,6,8,9 or not. *I do not want to check if my string contains just any random digits or not.*

I don't care how many times the digit is present. If any one of the above digits is present in the string even once, I want to stop right there and return true.

what regex can be used to match this string?

Is there any faster way to do it instead of using regex?
I am using Java 8.

**EDIT**: I already found lots solutions online for checking if a string contains digits or not. Those solutions don't work here because I want to **optimally** find out if my string (of length~10^15 characters) contains specific digits or not.

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ can help you testing your regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18591205/7118307

Comment: hmmm if you take some regex tutorial you would have figured out the solution by yourself, anyway I think the real question is "is there a faster way than using regex"

Comment: no that just answers the first part of my question. I am still looking for a faster way if possible.

Comment: if that's so you shouldn't accept it(sorry Tim :) )

Comment: it's funny that java doesn't have this as a built-in !!!, apache's commons-lang has `StringUtils`, worth checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern `.*[014689].*` along with [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
String input = "1 Hello World";
if (input.matches(".*[014689].*")) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your String is so very big that you have to read it from an InputStream, I'd advise something of the likes :

```
public static final Pattern TO_MATCH = Pattern.compile("[014689]");

public static boolean hasDigits(InputStream is, int bufferSize){
    BufferedReader l_read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset()),bufferSize);
    return l_read.lines().filter(s -> TO_MATCH.matcher(s).find()).findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Where you can tweak buffersize for performance.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (preg_match('/[^|]/', $string)) {    
// string contains characters other than |  
}
```

or:

```
if (strlen(str_replace('|', '', $string)) > 0) {   
// string contains characters other than |  
}
```