# Java, how to check if a string contains a digit?

Tags: java

how do I check if a string contains a digit?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    s1 = "Hello32"; //should be true`enter code here`
    s2 = "He2llo"; //should be true
    s3 = "Hello"; //should be false
}
```

Comment: Post code which u have tried so far

Comment: The refered duplicate is finding and extracting, not matching only.

Comment: @davidxxx yes, but many answers don't extract; for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18590949/1796579

Comment: @Henry Indeed. I had not seen it .It is a pity that we cannot split a question in two and group answers attached to.

Answer (score 6):

With a regex you could search at least a digit among any (zero or more) characters:

```
boolean hasDigit = s1.matches(".*\\d+.*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this it might help you

```
String regex = "\\d+";
System.out.println("abc45hdg".matches(regex));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but using that regex with a pattern and a matcher will I think work.

Answer (score 1):

In java

public boolean containsNumber(String string)

{

```
return string.matches(".*\\d+.*");
```

}