# How to use IndexOf to see if a string contain numbers

Tags: java

I need to use `indexOf` to find numbers inside a string, and it gives me the error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean.

```
public static boolean validPassword(String password) {
        if(password.length() >= 8 ){
            return true;

        }
        else if (password.indexOf("0")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want `password.contains("0")` or maybe `password.indexOf("0")!=-1`

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `indexOf` to see what it returns?

Comment: Oh wow thanks it works. And another questions, how would I make to check if it has any number?

Comment: @GBlodgett Yes i did but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a String contains numbers Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590901/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use index.  You can use `String.matches()`.

```java
      String str = "ksksks8ksksksksksks";
      System.out.println(str.matches(".*\\d.*"));
```

Honestly though, if you can do it anyway you want, I would simply write a method as follows.  Regular expressions are great for complicated patterns but they are also expensive in terms of processing.

```java
   public static boolean containsNumber(String str) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
         if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            found = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      return found;
   }
```

You could also modify the above and call it `indexOf` and iterate thru the characters using a regular for loop.  Then returning either the location of the first digit or -1 just like the `String` version of indexOf().

And finally, for fun, you could use the Streams capability of Java 8+.

```java
   public static boolean containsNumber(String str) {
      return str.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).count() > 0;
   }
```

Comment: The thing is I specifically need to use indexOf.

Comment: That does change things.  But you can't specify a regular expression using `IndexOf` so you will have to check for each digit (unless you are looking for a specific one).