# How to prevent String to have a int or number?

Tags: java

How to prevent or catch String for which the user has entered an int or a number?

ex.

```
String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Dog owner's First and Last name");
```

then if I input **Dave Har1234**, I want to catch that number on the input then return to the `JOptionPane`.

Comment: you can explore regex(regular expressions)

Comment: FYI, `Dave Har1234` can easily be a completely valid name.

Comment: @dyukha - Can you give an example of a legal jurisdiction which would permit someone to register their name as `Dave Har1234`.  I am curious.

Comment: str.matches(".*\\d.*"); will work. you can look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590901/check-if-a-string-contains-numbers-java

Comment: In response to a deleted comment: no I can't prove that there is no such jurisdiction.  However, I know of no examples where it is permitted.  Even the esteemed W3C article on this subject (["Personal Names around the world"](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names) ) doesn't mention digits in names, or a (real) need to support them.

Comment: @StephenC, I couldn't find a jurisdiction (some countries have a list of what names are allowed, but others have nothing at all). There are a lot of links (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law) which state something like "some states ban the use of numerals", which suggests that other states don't. Since I didn't find any articles claiming that it's universally prohibited, then, as a programmer, I must assume that it's allowed.

Comment: Recovered: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - @StephenC can you prove there is a jurisdiction in **every** country not permuting it? And what about nicknames (e.g. in some association/club/...)? But somehow I don't think that matters to the OP

Comment: Carlos - I have seen that page before.  It is not actually talking about legally permitted names.   Plus, it starts by saying this: *"It of course does not, because anything someone tells you is their name is — by definition — an appropriate identifier for them."*.  That might be philosophically correct, but it is not legally correct.  (Or practical.  Imagine: "My name is a rock that I keep in my back pocket.  And I'm not lending it to you.")

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only check if the complete string is a number. For that use the following check `inp.matches("\\d")`

You can check a complete example here https://onecompiler.com/java/3v5pffkbz

Comment: OP wants to also check if part of the string is a number

Comment: put .* at the front and the back. ".*\d.*"  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590949/908821

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputStr = "abc00123xyz4560";  // Input String for matching
      String regexStr = "[0-9]+";            // Regex to be matched


      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);

      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
       while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println("find() found substring \"" + matcher.group()
               + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start()
               + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
      }


    }
}
```

you can try this code to catch if user has entered any number in between string.

Can run and check code here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler