# How can check if a java string contains numbers and letters?

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
    button = findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    view = findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
    String x = editText.getText().toString();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//Checking if edit text field is left empty.
            if (editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.text_label, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }//Checking if editText field is numeric.
            else if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(x)){
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.text_number, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                textView.setText(NATOConverter("" + editText.getText().toString()));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hello guys im struggling trying to figure out how to check if a my edittext value contains letters and numbers im trying to display a snackbar if the user enters for example "JDF23D" telling them to remove the numbers but my error is no matter what it stays on that else if what would you suggest?

Comment: Out of respect for the reader, use proper grammar and case in your typing. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

Comment: This Question is quite confusing. Needs a rewrite to clearly state your goal, your undesired results, and where you think the problem lies.

Comment: It is kinda clear to me. Just a bit of careful reading

Answer (score 2):

Try next code

```
if (editText.getText().toString().matches(".*[0-9].*")){
            //some code
        }
        else{
           //some code 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the string contains a number, you should use this,

```
public boolean containsDigit(String x){
for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        if(48 <= (int) (x.charAt(i)) <= 57)
            return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Returns true if even one character is a number, else false.

Comment: Always pass in the current value of the edittext here. Using `edittext.getText().toString()` as the parameter. Don't use the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

You use this method:

```
TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(x)
```

but this method checks if your string **only** contains digits. So your example "JDF23D" will `return false`.

You can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591205/14321268)

Answer (score 0):

Try more simplest

```
boolean match = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s).find();
```