# how to split one text into multiple text files

Tags: java, file

I have the following Text:

```
1
(some text)
   /
2
(some text)
       /
.
.
    /
8519
(some text)
```

and I want to split this text into several text-files where each file has the name of the number before the text i.e. (`1.txt`, `2.txt`) and so on, and the content of this file will be the text.

I tried this code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("(Path)\\doc.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        // sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    String[] arrOfStr = str.split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrOfStr.length; i++) {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("(Path)" + arrOfStr[i].charAt(0) + ".txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(arrOfStr[i].substring(1));
        writer.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

this code works for files 1-9. However, things go wrong for files 10-8519 since I took the first number in the string (`arrOfStr [i].charAt(0)`) I know my solution is insufficient any suggestions?

Comment: You should search for extracting numbers from strings or performing a substring with a regular expression after the first number. 

If your text is very consistent, i.e. you have a leading number in each entry in the array, you could even perform a substring at the first "space": yourNumber =  arrOfStr[i].substring(0, arrOfStr[i].indexOf(" "));

Comment: I'm surprised your StringBuilder or `arrOfStr` doesn't pop.  I would first re-write, like you tried earlier, to process things as you read them.  You also know your problem - you're only looking at 1 character `char(0)`.

Comment: @CopyJosh thanx for your answer... it would be great but when I split the text thier is no space between the numbers and the first string so it will take the number+the first word as yourNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, considering there isn't a space between the leading integer and the first word, the substring at the first space doesn't work.

This question/answer has a few options that should help, the one using regex (\d+) being the simplest one imo, and copied below.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(arrOfStr[i]);
matcher.find();
int yourNumber = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
```

[Given a string find the first embedded occurrence of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742680/given-a-string-find-the-first-embedded-occurrence-of-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is that you only take the first digit. You could enumerate the first characters until you find a non digit character ( `arrOfStr[i].charAt(j) <'0'  || arrOfStr[i].charAt(j) > '9'` ) but it shoud be easier to user a Scanner and an appropriate regexp.

```
int index = new Scanner(arrOfStr[i]).useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();
```

The delimiter is precisely any group of non-digit character

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a quick solution for the given problem. You can test and do proper exception handling.

package practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;

public class FileNioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path path = Paths.get("C:/Temp/readme.txt");

        try {
            List<String> contents = Files.readAllLines(path);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String folderName = "C:/Temp/";
            String fileName = null;
            String previousFileName = null;

            // Read from the stream
            for (String content : contents) {// for each line of content in contents
                if (content.matches("-?\\d+")) {  // check if it is a number (based on your requirement) 
                    fileName = folderName + content + ".txt";   // create a file name with path
                    if (sb != null && sb.length() > 0) {  // this means if content present to write in the file
                        writeToFile(previousFileName, sb);  // write to file
                        sb.setLength(0);              // clearing buffer
                    }
                    createFile(fileName);           // create a new file if number found in the line
                    previousFileName = fileName;    // store the name to write content in previous opened file. 
                } else {
                    sb.append(content);             // keep storing the content to write in the file.
                }
                System.out.println(content);// print the line
            }
            if (sb != null && sb.length() > 0) {
                writeToFile(fileName, sb);
                sb.setLength(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();// handle exception here
        }
    }

    private static void createFile (String fileName) {
        Path newFilePath = Paths.get(fileName);

        if (!Files.exists(newFilePath)) {
            try {
                Files.createFile(newFilePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile (String fileName, StringBuffer sb) {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), sb.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like your answer would include the delimiter “//“ in the text files, and since it’s not checking for that, a case that a line has a number but isn’t separated by // would still create a file by mistake

Comment: Not really. Tested with file having number in each line as given
 by @Abeer.  1
This is First File
2
This is Second File
This is Second File
3
This is third File
This is third File
This is third File
4
This is fourth File
This is fourth File
This is fourth File
This is fourth File
5
This is Fifth File
This is Fifth File
This is Fifth File
This is Fifth File
This is Fifth File
6
7
8
9
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file
This is nineth file